# Passing params: to Web API works with $http.get but not $http.Post

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

AngularJS 1.59

This API call works with `$http.get`.

JS ViewModel

```
  $scope.placeOrder = function () { //'api/order/create'
    var order = { AccountId : accountId, Amount : $scope.subTotal,
      Tax: $scope.tax, Shipping: $scope.shipping }
    var orderJSON = JSON.stringify(order);
    viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/order/create', { params: { order: orderJSON } },
      function (result) {
        var orderId = result.data;
      });
  }
```

App.js

```
self.apiGet = function (uri, data, success, failure, always) {
  self.isLoading = true;
  self.modelIsValid = true;
  $http.get(AlbumApp.rootPath + uri, data)
      .then(function (result) {
        success(result);
        if (always != null)
          always();
        self.isLoading = false;
      }, function (result) {
        if (failure == null) {
          if (result.status != 400)
            self.modelErrors = [result.status + ': ' + result.statusText +
              ' - ' + result.data];
          else
            self.modelErrors = [result.data + ''];
          self.modelIsValid = false;
        }
        else
          failure(result);
        if (always != null)
          always();
        self.isLoading = false;
      });
}

self.apiPost = function (uri, data, success, failure, always) {
  self.isLoading = true;
  self.modelIsValid = true;
  $http.post(AlbumApp.rootPath + uri, data)
      .then(function (result) {
        success(result);
        if (always != null)
          always();
        self.isLoading = false;
      }, function (result) {
        if (failure == null) {
          if (result.status != 400)
            self.modelErrors = [result.status + ': ' + result.statusText + ' - ' + result.data];
          else self.modelErrors = [result.data];
          self.modelIsValid = false;
        }
        else failure(result);
        if (always != null) always();
        self.isLoading = false;
      });
}
```

APIController

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("create")]
public IHttpActionResult Create(string order) { 
  var _order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(order); ... }
```

But since this is a Create function I want to use `$http.post`.  When I change the call to

```
  $scope.placeOrder = function () { //'api/order/create'
    var order = { AccountId : accountId, Amount : $scope.subTotal,
      Tax: $scope.tax, Shipping: $scope.shipping }
    var orderJSON = JSON.stringify(order);
    viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/order/create', { params: { order: orderJSON } },
      //null,
      function (result) {
        var orderId = result.data;
      });
  }
```

and my controller Action to

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")] 
public IHttpActionResult Create(string order) { 
  var _order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(order); ... }
```

I get a 404 error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50597/api/order/create'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'OrderApi' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing some conceptual point or do I have an error in my code?

**Solution:** (Thank you Giovani)

`params:` needs to be passed to the `config` in the `$http.get` and `$http.post`.  The two methods have different signatures.

In `apiGet` renamed `data` to `config`.
In `apiPost` added a `config`.

In `apiPost` call added a `null` so the `params:` is passed to `config` rather than `data`.

App.js

```
self.apiGet = function (uri, config, success, failure, always) {
  self.isLoading = true;
  self.modelIsValid = true;
  $http.get(AlbumApp.rootPath + uri, config)
...

self.apiPost = function (uri, data, config, success, failure, always) {
  self.isLoading = true;
  self.modelIsValid = true;
  $http.post(AlbumApp.rootPath + uri, data, config)
```

JS ViewModel

```
  $scope.placeOrder = function () { //'api/order/create'
    var order = { AccountId : accountId, Amount : $scope.subTotal,
      Tax: $scope.tax, Shipping: $scope.shipping }
    var orderJSON = JSON.stringify(order);
    viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/order/create', null, { params: { order: orderJSON } },
      function (result) {
        var orderId = result.data;
      }); }
```

Comment: You might want to check your route configuration on the web api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$http.get() and $http.post() have a different method signature. [more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

```
$http.get(<URL>, <DATA (params, responseType, etc..)>)
$http.post(<URL>, <BODY_DATA>, <DATA (params, responseType, etc..)>
```